# Unable to set MTU size on windows network adapter

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

One of my network adapters (Edimax 10 Gigabit Ethernet SFP+) is reporting an MTU of 1496. I have verified this by checking the maximum captured packet size in WireShark - 1514 bytes, minus Ethernet header and FCS, which results in a payload size of 1496 bytes. I want to change the MTU to 1500. OS is Windows Server 2019 and Hyper-V is installed. The adapter is connected to a virtual switch, and the management OS is sharing the network adapter.

Running Powershell to query adapter properties we get:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object -Property InterfaceDescription, ifIndex, MtuSize

InterfaceDescription                                ifIndex MtuSize
--------------------                                ------- -------
Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter                         25    1500
Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection               16    1500
Edimax 10 Gigabit Ethernet SFP+ PCI Express Adapter       4    1496
```

Attempting to set the MTU for Edimax 10 Gigabit fails:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "4" store=persistent mtu=1500
The parameter is incorrect.
```

Attempting to set the MTU for Intel(R) 82574L with same command succeeds:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "16" store=persistent mtu=1500
Ok.
```

I have also tried to add the registy keys to set this directly. After rebooting, Get-NetAdapter returns the same 1496 MTU value, seemingly ignoring the registry key.

I have the same network adapter in a Windows 10 machine, same problem.

How do I change the MTU?

Comment: Which driver do you have installed? If you have the plug and play Windows driver for the device, try installing the manufacturer's driver for it (from https://www.edimax.com/edimax/mw/cufiles/files/download/Driver_Utility/EN-9320SFP_Windows_Driver.zip)

Comment: If you cannot set MTU in the adapter (not possible for some NICs), can you set MTU in the router?  This is possible on the routers I have used.

Comment: So apparently disabling QoS IEEE 802.1q Offloading in the adapter properties allows me to set the MTU to 1500. If QoS IEEE 802.1q Offloading is enabled, an additional 4 bytes are added to the packet for the VLAN tag, reducing the available payload size to 1496 bytes. I'm not sure at this stage if disabling offloading has broken any guest VMs that use VLAN tagging in conjunction with the edge router that also uses vlan tagging. But the hyper-v host is reporting 1500 now.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**: Disabling the option "QoS (IEEE 802.1q) Offloading" in the adapter properties allows me to set the MTU to 1500. I'm not sure if this is expected behaviour, or if disabling the option has broken anything else in the network, but I will mark as answered as it addresses the fundamental question - the adapter was rejecting the higher MTU as it could not comply given its current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are part of a corporation, see if your corporate IT are installing software called ZScaler ZCC.

Zscaler is a security application. For efficiency, it limits the MTU packet size to 1500.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).